# Angular ng-messages similar functionality for Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Because of IE8 support I am restricted to using Angular 1.2.x, I am trying to implement a custom directive that shows a form field and form error messages for the field that validates with a custom validator.

This is my validator:

```
angular.module("validator", [])
    .directive('myValidator', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',

            link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

                function myValidator(ngModelValue) {

                    switch(attr.myValidator){
                        case 'twitter':
                            if (/^@(\w{1,15})$/.test(ngModelValue)) {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('twitterValidate', true);
                            } else {
                                ctrl.$setValidity('twitterValidate', false);
                            }
                            break;
                }

                // return ngModelValue displayed to the user
                return ngModelValue;
            }

            // add parser to existing parsers
            ctrl.$parsers.push(myValidator);

        }
    };
});
```

and custom directive:

```
angular.module('form-fields', [])
    .directive('TwitterField', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {
                twitter: '=',
                isRequired: '=required'
            },
            templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',
        }
    })
```

and template:

```
<label>Twitter</label>
<input type="text" id="twitter" ng-model="twitter" my-validator="twitter" ng-required="isRequired">
```

This all works fine, I can use the directives in a `<form>` and they validate properly. I can access the $scope.form.twitter and see errors so I can make error messages in the surrounding form, but I want this in the directive. Is this possible?